# how to category (Objective-C feature) method in one class without its header file?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My current challenage is that I need to category(Objective-C feature) one specific method in one specific class, unfortunately, I don't have the header file of that class. Is there any solution?

thanks!

Comment: We can't make heads or tails out of what you're asking.

Comment: Hot Licks. What do you mean heads or tails here? thanks.

Comment: What shall I do now? thanks.

Comment: Write a clearer question -- one where people can understand what you're asking.  We don't demand perfect English here, but we need to understand it.

Comment: thanks.I edit my question. I suppose you didn't catch the meaning of "category" in my question before.

Answer (score 0):

you can't have a category without a header -- in way would be to define a category on NSObject and then use the className of the class with the method to swivel the method you are looking for

**In a nutshell:**
With swizzling you can actually replace a selector of a given class. (other than with a category)

## example

### usage

```
@interface NSObject (myClass)
@end

@implementation NSObject (myClass)

+ (void)load
{
    Class class = objc_getClass("MyClass");
    [class swizzleInstanceMethodWithSelector:@selector(myMethod:)
                                withSelector:@selector(xchg_myMethod:)];
}

- (void)xchg_myMethod:(id)arg1
{
    NSLog(@"%@", arg1);
}
@end
```

### helper that does the swizzling

```
@interface NSObject (MethodSwizzle)
+ (void)swizzleInstanceMethodWithSelector:(SEL)original_selector withSelector:(SEL)alternative_selector;
@end

#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSObject (MethodSwizzle)

+ (void)swizzleInstanceMethodWithSelector:(SEL)originalSelector withSelector:(SEL)overrideSelector {
    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector);
    Method overrideMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, overrideSelector);
    if (class_addMethod(self, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(overrideMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(overrideMethod))) {
        class_replaceMethod(self, overrideSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
    } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, overrideMethod);
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks Daij-Djan. Your solution is really magical. Now I can do anything I want! I'm sorry to late to reply till now. I'm busy in the past weeks and I only have time to verify it in my codes.

Comment: Just one comment, do I need to replace self with [self class] in the function of swizzleInstanceMethodWithSelector? It seems there is warning in the building. thanks.

Comment: Please don't worry it, I tried both, all are working.

Comment: One more question. I know the risk of method swizzling, but how about the risk of category to the NSObject? thanks.